# How to set page margin of 9" by 6"

Tags: geometry

I am writing solution manual of matric mathematics book. To design this book in latex I am using this geometry.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{amssymb}

%\usepackage{amused}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%\usepackage{eureka}

%\def\principaladviser#1{\gdef\@principaladviser{#1}}

\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\usepackage[all]{xy}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%\usepackage{tikzpicture}

%\usepackage{breqn}

%\usepackage{verbatim}

%\usepackage{apst-all}

%\usepackage{xy-pic}

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

%\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\usepackage{dsfont}\let\mathbb\mathds
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{eqlist}

%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%\usepackage{mwe}

%\usepackage{breqn}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
%\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
%\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
%\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}

\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}

\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}

\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newcommand{\BibUrl}{\url}
%\def\be{\begin{equation}
%\def\ee\end{equation}}
%\def\bea{\begin{eqnarray}
%\def\eea{\end{eqnarray}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

But the press wants me set the page margin of 9" by 6". The maximum empty space on the top and bottom should be 1".

I do not know how to set this setting.
I just know how to write in latex but how to set the mention page size margin? please help!

Comment: You are already using the `geometry` package, read its manual. It has a super easy user interface.

Comment: @daleif I try this $\usepackage[total={6in, 9in}, twocolumn, margin=1in, twoside]{geometry}$ but when i run and get the dpf, then zoom page level in pdf to 100 it has still page margin 11 by 8.5.

Comment: Show your work. And please make your example minimal 85% of what you list here are not related to your question.

Comment: Also your question does not make much sense. Is it the text block that needs to be 6" by 9", 9" margins make no sense.

Comment: When you say `total={6in,9in},margin=1in`, the `margin=...` is negating the `total=...`, See the example just before section 3 in the manual. `margin` sets all the margins and recalculates the text block from that. But you just set attempted to set the text block via `total`. So instead of `margin` use `left` and say `top` as in the example in the marnual.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `geometry` correctly. `total={6in,9in}` sets the size of the text block to be 6in by 9in. But your subsequent `margin=1in` recalculates the text block to have the width of the paper minus 2in and the height of the paper minus 2in.

See the example in the `geometry` manual right before section 3.

Here is an MWE with some added tikz to show where things are. Try for your self to see what happens with `\usepackage[total={6in, 9in}, twocolumn, margin=1in, twoside]{geometry}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[twocolumn,total={6in,9in},left=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\kant[2-5]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

  \draw ($(current page.north west)+(1in,0)$)     -- ++(0,-30cm);
  \draw ($(current page.north west)+(1in+6in,0)$) -- ++(0,-30cm);

  \draw ($(current page.north west)+(0,-1in)$)     -- ++(30cm,0);
  \draw ($(current page.north west)+(0,-1in-9in)$) -- ++(30cm,0);

  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \node[minimum width=1cm,draw,circle] (a) at (0,0) {$\alpha$};
      \node[minimum width=1cm,draw,circle] (b) at ($(a)+(2,0)$) {$\beta$};
      \node[minimum width=1cm,draw,circle] (c) at ($(b)+(2,0)$) {$\gamma$};

      \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
      \draw[->] (c) -- (b);
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dalief Please brother set it for me I tried a lot but i can not get the desire.